# CSS last-child:after is not eliminating the last separator character in a UL

Tags: css

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rRKU3/25/

Here is the essence of the layout:

```
 <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="rel">
            <div class="abs">1</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rel">
            <div class="abs">2</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...etc
 </ul>
```

The divs help place text in relative and absolute containers for type positioning and transitions.

This Nav Bav currently looks like the following:

```
1   /   2   /   3   /   4   /   5   /
```

I would like it to drop the last "/" separator character to look like the following:

```
1   /   2   /   3   /   4   /   5
```

When I create a Nav Bar, that is made of only ul and li items, using the "li:last-child:after" selector works correctly and eliminates the last separator.  When I create it using the above technique, with 2 div containers inside the li, I cannot figure out the selector I need, to overwrite the :after selector that creates the separator in the first place.

Here is what I have tried:

Selector that creates the separator;

```
    ul > li > .rel > .abs:after {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0; 
        left: 55px;
        content: "/";
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;
    }
```

Selector to overwrite the above selector (I tried all of versions below and none work):

```
    /* .rel > .abs ~ .rel > .abs { */
    /* li > .rel > .abs ~ li > .rel > .abs { */
    /* ul > li > .rel > .abs ~ ul > li > .rel > .abs { */
    /* .rel .abs:last-child { */
    /* .rel > .abs:last-child { */
    /* li > .rel > .abs:last-child { */
    ul > li > .rel > .abs:last-child {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        /*left: 55px; */
        content: "+";
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;
    }
```

Instead of overwriting the separator, this last selector somehow eliminates the hover (not mentioned, but you can see it in the jsfiddle). These last several lines are commented out in the jsfiddle so you can see the effect I am going for on hover.

Thank you for your esteemed knowledge of CSS selectors!

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/rRKU3/26/ Note that you don't need to override it, just change the selector to `ul > li:not(:last-child) > .rel > .abs:after {...}`

Comment: you haven't overwritten the `:after` of `.abs`. your selector should be `ul > li > .rel > .abs:last-child:after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following class in your CSS. It will remove the "/" from last child.

```
ul > li:last-child > .rel > .abs:after {
content: " ";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rRKU3/27/)